# Maximum number of dimensions in a Java array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Out of curiosity, how many dimensions of an array can you have in Java?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Java *language* does not limit the number of dimensions, but the Java *VM* spec limits the number of dimensions to 255.

For example, the following code will fail to compile:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] x;
    }
}
```

with error:

```
1.java:18: error: array type has too many dimensions
                 [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] x;
                                                  ^
1 error
```

(Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1 "An array type descriptor is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer dimensions.")

Comment: In other words, if you needed more than 255 (ha!), you would have to make the outer ones just arrays of objects and then cast them to the actual type once you got below 256.

Comment: This is interesting - I didn't know that. On one hand, I'm wondering why anyone would ever want to use an array of that dimensionality, and on the other, I'm wondering why they'd limit it like that.

Comment: @KennyTM: Well obviously. But if your array has 255+ dimensions, are you really worried about whether it's going to take 8 or 32 bits to store your array's dimensionality?

Comment: I for one can't wait to take advantage of java.util.BigArray for n-dimension arrays.  "255 dimensions ought to be enough for anybody." indeed.

Comment: @Cam but if you use a 32-bit value to store the number of dimensions, then it will take 32 bits even if you're just having 1D arrays.

Comment: @KennyTM: Not necessarily - a flag could be used at the beginning to show whether 32 or 8 bits are being used to store the number of dimensions.

Comment: @Cam it doesn't worth the complexity for something that's extremely rarely used.

Comment: @Cam Not to mention the fact that the flag has to take a bit as well, but 9 bits doesn't fit into memory well, so you're using 2 bytes for it now. Doubling the header on arrays. It's really just not worth it. If I saw a[3][4][3][1]...[4] in code I would crap my pants.

Comment: Sorry to say but in reality i guess Java support only one dimensional array. rest of all types are just array of arrays :)

Comment: Link to your proof of concept seems broken.

Answer (score 2):

Small experiment shows, that 255 dimensions is maximum. 256 causes compilation error;

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c8wL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking about

```
 Maximum number of dimensions in a Java array
```

is only one dimensional array is possible in java. because under the hood java treat multidimensional arrays as array of arrays.

Proof of concept: http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm

that's why its possible to have ragged arrays in Java as well!