# How many array dimensions are supported in Java like a[1][1][1][1]....[1]?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How many array dimension is supported in Java like `a[1][1][1][1]....[1]`?
Can I declare an unlimited number of dimensions for an array?

Comment: First hit on google for "maximum array dimension java" gives you [Max number of dimensions in a Java array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060538/max-number-of-dimensions-in-a-java-array)

Comment: The dimensions of an array must not exceed the number of array dimensions supported by the implementation which is typically 255.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The number of array dimensions are limited to 255.

The interesting thing is that there is no such limitation in Java programming language defined by JLS, but you can see in the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.multianewarray), that the array dimension is stored in 1 byte.

However, you can hardly meet this limitation on your day-to-day development. :-)

Comment: So this means that this particular JVM is limited by this right?

Comment: The most important point in this answer is "you can hardly meet this limitation on your day-to-day development. " . If you get close to this limit, there's probably a better approach to this.

Comment: @Bartdude frankly there should be a better approach before you hit 3. Except for corner cases like matrices maybe. Even in that case you can create a better data model.

Answer (score 4):

From the [JVM specs it is 255](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

> "An array type descriptor is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer
>   dimensions."

You may also check [Array type descriptor may have more than 255 dimensions](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4905765)

> JVMS-2 has the assertions about array dimensions:
>
> "4.10 Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine ... The number of
>   dimensions in an array is limited to 255 by the size of  the
>   dimensions opcode of the multianewarray instruction and by the 
>   constraints imposed on the multianewarray, anewarray, and newarray 
>   instructions by ?4.8.2. ..."
>
> and
>
> "4.4.1 The CONSTANT_Class_info Structure ... An array type descriptor
>   is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer dimensions." It looks like
>   the last assertion is applied to the chapter 4.4.1 only.
>
> But the chapters: 
>    2.7.5 Fully Qualified Names
>    4.2 The Internal Form of Fully Qualified Class and Interface Names
>    4.3 Descriptors (4.3.2 Field Descriptors and 4.3.3 Method Descriptors) say nothing about a number of dimensions limitation.
>
> Further, the following chapters:
>    4.4.6 The CONSTANT_NameAndType_info Structure 
>    4.5 Fields
>    4.6 Methods refer to definitions of field descriptors and method descriptors (descriptor_index) and also say nothing about a dimensions
>   limitation.
>
> So according to JVMS-2 the descriptor_index of
>   CONSTANT_NameAndType_info, field_info or method_info structures may
>   refer to field descriptor representing more than 255 dimensions or
>   method descriptor with similar ParameterDescriptor or
>   ReturnDescriptor.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that it can't have 256 dimensions, considering that a 0 dimensional array, isn't an array.

Comment: That's from the JVM specification. There's also the Java Language Specification, but there's no "Java specification".