# What is the maximum number of dimensions a C# multidimensional Array can hold? What about jagged ones?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a question that i cannot find an answer for, not even in the C# specifications. So before anyone goes, why would you use or need a N dimension array, remember that this is a question for knowledge purposes.

Comment: This is the first result of google search of the title of your question. I'm guessing you've heard about [google](http://www.google.com), right?

Comment: Oh spare me Zohar, the first results are about C++. Theres always some smart guy like you, isn't there?

Comment: Oops, sorry, second result. I guess that means your duplicate was justified... there's a reason I've never asked a question here in over a year of membership, it's because I search before I ask.

Comment: Congrats, you deserve a nobel prize.

Comment: I might have been a little over sarcastic in my first comment, maybe in my second one as well. It's been a hard day for me and I've blown some steam  on you, sorry about that. **but** I didn't say anything that isn't true. a google search would give you the exact same answer in less time and you wouldn't have to be pissed of by people like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the maximum *rank* of an array in C#. See the [documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array(v=vs.100).aspx), under "Remarks":

> An array can have a maximum of 32 dimensions.

For jagged arrays, it's implementation defined (usually more than 1000, for mono the limit seems to be 255) see the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713703/maximum-array-dimension-like-a1111-1-in-c-sharp) linked by Zohar in the commments to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the links schnaader, will close my question.

Comment: Note: Declaring an array with more dimensions does not generate a compiler error in VS2010. At run-time there will be a `TypeLoadException` that the array has "too many dimensions".