# Why does Java support 255 dimensional array , while in real life we rarely exceed more than 2D?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just curious, as I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060538/maximum-number-of-dimensions-in-a-java-array) that Java can have 255D arrays. What's the purpose of this? Do we ever need of 255D in real life or is it for some JVM level operations? How does it work under the hood?

Comment: Sometimes, it is not worth stopping you doing something. It's more effort to do so. There mere inconvenience of creating such an array is enough of a deterrent.

Comment: Sometimes when deciding "what should the max be" we like to pick nice "round" numbers that are much bigger than what we'd reasonably need if there is no strong reason to pick a lower limit. Supporting unlimited number of dimensions was probably impractical for various reasons, so they stuck with 255 just because it's "probably more than we'll ever need". And yes, mis-judging that "more than we'd ever need" has bitten us in the butt way more than once (see IPv4, the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane/UTF-16, ...).

Comment: Unsigned 8-bit [Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) can hold from 0 ... 255. I think javac using internal structure with 1-byte for array dimension. Technically array in a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to the block of memory. So `int a[100]; `a[1] = 1`. Some mashie code will looks like `mov $arr,%rbx lea [%rbx+4],%rax mov $1,[%rax]` i.e. get base address, then add 4 bytes and assign value to the memory at this address. Dimension is just a way to calculate the address.

Comment: To sort of answer the question, some financial models use 4 dimensions.  I'm not enough of a math wizard to understand the models.  I just know they exist.

Answer (score 0):

The Java language does not have any limit for the number of dimensions of an array, but the Java Virtual Machine Specification limits the number of dimensions to 255.

For example,

```
public class MultiDimensionalArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  [][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
                [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] i = null;
        
}
```

Write the above code in your IDE, you will see compile error (*"Too many array dimensions. Maximum is 255"*) and you can also see this error in the screenshot below. Because these are 256 dimensions. To remove this error just remove one dimension from this array.

[image]

For more details check below link:
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but my question is, why do we need so many dimensions ? Isn't 3 or 4D was enough to solve the real life problems ?

Comment: See the dimension which we use is based upon requirement. sometimes we use only one dimensional array . why? because it is our requirement to use one dimensional not two dimensional. So sometimes it might be possible that we have to declare array more than three or four dimensional

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional arrays are an extended form of one-dimensional arrays and are frequently used to store data for mathematic computations, image processing, and record management. As we know that we can store one datatype in array, this can help us to process large amount of data to obtain a single output. For example, to process a single image from multiple images we can use 255 dimensional array to store large amount of data in the form of images to obtain a fine and accurate image out of that raw data.

Comment: Can you point to any example of the usage of an array with more than say even 5 dimensions? That might go a long way toward clarifying this answer.